# Sci fi book where the protagonists have to keep ahead of the terminator line on a planet

Tags: story-identification, books

I am pretty sure the author was called Adam Douglas (not Douglas Adams). Although I may be wrong.

There was a hairy mammal type character that was on the good guys side.

Laser whips were in use throughout the book.

I also seem to remember some sort of terminator line (possibly of fire) approaching around the planet, this kept the main protagonists on the move ahead of it.

I also have memory of reading a 2nd book by the same author which focused on a ship crew crash landing in a large lake, floating on parts of the wreckage. Before then being attacked by something from within the water.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: Welcome Luke. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. Can you remember when you read it, the approximate year of publication?

Comment: Hmm. ISFDB only lists one novel by an Adam Douglas and it's a werewolf book; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?212831

Comment: Any chance this is "West of January"? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110789/28516